# custom-environment-variables.js cannot be read error in react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a React + ASP.NET application run from Visual Studio. For some reason I am receiving the following error:

> Error: Config file /config/custom-environment-variables.js cannot be
>   read. Error code is: undefined. Error message is:
>   FileSystem.readFileSync is not a function

I have had no intentions to use custom environment variable. I have no idea why I am receiving this error. Also, I could not find much resources on the internet about this issue. I have been spending the whole day un/installing the npm and nodejs but no help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 1 day, I found the solution, which was in my case to delete this stupid line of code:

> import config from 'config';

I do not understand why this suddenly started to cause problems since it was always there. I hope this helps others.

Comment: That didn't work. Where have you created config folder?

Comment: I do not know, probably it is created with some react packages. But, the problem was that in one of the react components I had `import config from 'config';` code, which was not necessary and causing the error. So, I just deleted it.

Comment: Then how did you use config package?

Comment: Agreed @RohitSawai. This doesn't at all address the problem, rather removing the package in question. Have you since figured out a solution?

Comment: This comes from the node-config npm package.

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand the solution but;
I wrote my config.js. Afterward, export it, add it .gitignore as well

mycongif.js

```
const config = {
token: "xaxaxax"
}

export default config;
```

and I use it

```
import config from './config/myconfig'
console.log(config.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

just by removing this line in your on of the files =>  'import config from 'config';

it's just due to auto import by an editor

Comment: please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve your answer